# Turn off exception messages by another website after window.open in Output Window

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have some code to open another window tab on another site.

```
<script>
    function F(field) {
        window.open("http://www.thefreedictionary.com/" + field.innerHTML);
    }
</script>

<span id='t1' onclick='F(this)'>dog</span>
```

The problem is, after I run this code in debug mode in IE browser. In the Output Window, I keep seeing the Exception messages being thrown, such as:

```
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 4628 in http://b.scorecardresearch.com/rs/vce_st.js
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
```

Sometimes I get the "Unhandled Exceptions" message window that ask for "Break" or "Continue".

I would like to know how if there is a way to turn these things off? To turn off any exceptions that come from another website.

But I still would like to see exceptions being thrown if it is my domain.